# SwiftUI not releasing model instances

Tags: swiftui, combine

Having a SwiftUI project generated by Xcode, and adding a custom `MyView` with a `MyViewModel`.
The `ContentView` just renders `MyView`.

The problem:

1. When the `ContentView` gets reloaded (the reload button changes its state), `MyViewModel` gets somehow disconnected from `MyView` (the `MyView` counter stops incrementing in the UI when the button is clicked), but the console logs show the incrementation works.
2. If the model subscribes to a publisher, it does not get unsubscribed because the instance is not released. Therefore, the instances still process incoming messages and alter the app's data and state.

Looking at the instance counters and memory addresses in the console:

1. Every time the `ContentView` gets refreshed, a new `MyView` and `MyViewModel` instances get created. However, the counter incrementation uses the original first-created model instance.
2. Some model instances did not get released.

*EDIT:* The model needs to be recreated every time `MyView` is recreated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    private var reloadCounter = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.reloadCounter += 1 },
                   label: { Text("Reload view") })

            Text("Reload counter: \(reloadCounter)")

            MyView().environmentObject(MyViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject
    private var model: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.model.counter += 1 },
                   label:  { Text("Increment counter") })

            Text("Counter value: \(model.counter)")
        }
        .frame(width: 480, height: 300)
    }

    init() { withUnsafePointer(to: self) { print("Initialising MyView struct instance \(String(format: "%p", $0))") }}
}
```

```
import Combine

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private static var instanceCount: Int = 0 { didSet {
        print("SettingsViewModel: \(instanceCount) instances")
    }}

    @Published
    var counter: Int = 0 { didSet {
        print("Model counter: \(counter), self: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
    }}

    init() { print("Initialising MyViewModel class instance \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())"); Self.instanceCount += 1 }
    deinit { print("Deinitialising MyViewModel class instance \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())"); Self.instanceCount -= 1 }
}
```

Any clue what did I do wrong?

The image below depicts the app's UI after all the actions in the logs were performed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest Xcode (tested with Xcode 14.3.1) the model leaking does not happen anymore.

Also, there is the [@StateObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/) property wrapper available that allows views to instantiate the models.

Answer (score 0):

You create new view model on every refresh, so just move it outside `body`, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    private var reloadCounter = 0

    private let vm = MyViewModel()    // << here !!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.reloadCounter += 1 },
                   label: { Text("Reload view") })

            Text("Reload counter: \(reloadCounter)")

            MyView().environmentObject(vm)   // << reference only !!
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: if you don't need it deeply in sub-view hierarchy then consider to use `@ObservedObject` instead of `@EnvironmentObject` and pass reference via constructor (because environment object is stored somewhere outside and you have less control over its life-cycle)*

Comment: The thing is I need a new model every time the MainView gets created - it must be fresh so that MyView gets set to the model's default values.
The provided example is a bit simplified. In reality, there is a bit deeper hierarchy (that's why I use EnvironmentObject).